# How to assert/match active records in a custom data structure in RSpec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a controller which assigns a instances variable

```
def index
  @groups = Group.get_by_category_and_user
end
```

@groups is a hash of the following structure

```
# {"group_name" => [active_record_obj1, active_record_obj2] }
```

In RSpec test when I created the same hash

```
  group_category = create(:category) 
  public_group = create(:group, category: group_category)

  my_groups = { group_category.name => [public_group] }

  get :index

  expect(assigns(:groups)).to eq(my_groups)
```

where my_groups is the expected object. 
It doesn't pass because the activerecord object are different but of the same database record.

Rspec output

`-"Luigi Hoeger" => [#<Group:0x007ff0d8cc1e30 id: 7, user_id: 7, name: "Site 7", url: "site-7", submission_start_date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 10:57:44 PDT -07:00, submission_end_date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 10:57:44 PDT -07:00]
       +"Luigi Hoeger" => [#<Group:0x007ff0d92b83e8 id: 7, user_id: 7, name: "Site 7", url: "site-7", submission_start_date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 10:57:44 PDT -07:00, submission_end_date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 10:57:44 PDT -07:00]`

How should we assert for the test to pass ?

Comment: Please post the RSpec output.

Comment: @AndyWaite Added the Rspec output

Comment: What does `assigns(:groups)[group_category.name][0] == public_group[group_category.name][0]` evaluate to? The only think I can think of is that `Group` has redefined the ActiveRecord equality definition (see http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveResource/Base/%3D%3D).

Comment: I'd advise you to test the request's response instead of the controller's internal assignments. That being said, it's weird that the test isn't passing. I've reproduced the structure in a application of mine and had no failure. As said above, is the `Group#==` method being redefined?